# Performance chart of a counter with Graphite

Tags: python, graphite, statsd

I want a chart like the following which shows that the number of registered users was 0 at 9:41 am and increased by 41 on 9:46 am:

http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/7989/localhostscreencapture2.png

But I got this graphite chart (I incremented the statsd counter by 41 at 9:46 am):

http://img829.imageshack.us/img829/8702/graphitedevreqordercom.png

My render request was (someone recommended the hitcount method to me):

render/?width=586&height=308&_salt=1336642203.533&target=hitcount(stats_counts.reqorder.staging.community.1.membership.total, "1min")&from=09%3A40_20120509&until=09%3A50_20120509

How can I change the render url request to get a chart like this:

http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/7989/localhostscreencapture2.png

Answer (score 2):

You want the `integral()` function instead of the `hitcount()`:
http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.10/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.integral

So your full query would be:

```
integral(stats_counts.reqorder.staging.community.1.membership.total)
```

Note though that result of `integral()` always starts at 0 at the left side of the graph though. I don't think there's a way around that.